# How to use SequenceEqual with StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase in F#?

Tags: .net, linq, f#

In C# I have this code snippet:

```cs
string[] words =  { "how", "are", "you" };
string[] words2 = { "HOW", "are", "YOU" };

var result = words.SequenceEqual(words2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

And `result` will have the value true.

In F# I want to do the same:

```
let words =  [|"how", "are", "you"|]
let words2 = [|"HOW", "are", "YOU"|]

let result = words.SequenceEqual(words2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

But the compiler complains with:

> The type `StringComparer` is not compatible with the type `Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string * string * string>`

How can I use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnore` for my example in F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `;` to separate array elements:

```
let words =  [|"how"; "are"; "you"|]
let words2 = [|"HOW"; "are"; "YOU"|]
```

`,` is used to separate elements in a tuple, so you currently have two 1-element arrays containing a 3-element tuple of type `string * string * string`.